# OpenLayers 3 - draw polyline vertices only

Tags: line, openlayers-3, vertices, multipoint

I'm using OpenLayers 3 and I need to show only the vertices of a polyline. For exemple see this image :

[image]

I want to be able to show only the red squares (they can be something else than squares, like circles). Using markers is not an option for performance issue, my lines can be huge (500 000 vertices).

Currently I have a working code :

```
// Define the style for vertex polyline :
var yellowVertexPolylineStyle = [
    new ol.style.Style({
        image: new ol.style.Circle({
            radius: 1.5,
            fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                color: 'yellow'
            })
        }),
        geometry: function(feature) {
            return new ol.geom.MultiPoint(feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates());
        }
    })
];

// Create the line :
var lineLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({

    zIndex: 1000,
    source: new ol.source.Vector({ features: [new ol.Feature({ geometry: myLine })] }),
    style: yellowVertexPolylineStyle
});

// Add the layer :
map.addLayer(lineLayer);
```

But this is causing performance issue when the polyline is quite big (> 10 000 points).

Using an ol.geom.MultiPoint geometry is even worse. Does someone knows a better way?

EDIT : I'm trying this now :

```
// Define the style for vertex polyline :
var yellowVertexPolylineStyle = [
    new ol.style.Style({
        image: new ol.style.Circle({
            radius: 1.5,
            fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                color: 'yellow'
            })
        }),
        geometry: function(feature) {

            var geom = feature.get('stylegeom');
            if (!geom || (geom && geom.getCoordinates().length !== feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates().length) ) {

                geom = new ol.geom.MultiPoint(feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates());
                feature.set('stylegeom', geom);
            }

            return geom;
        }
    })
];
```

I'll come back here to tell if it works...

Answer (score 0):

You need to cache your style geometry, otherwise it will be calculated for every rendered frame, e.g.

```js
geometry: function(feature) {
  var geom = feature.get('stylegeom');
  if (!geom) {
    geom = new ol.geom.MultiPoint(feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates());
    feature.set('stylegeom', geom);
  }
  return geom;
}
```

If your feature geometry changes, you'll need to update the style geometry too:

```js
source.on('changefeature', function(evt) {
  feature.set('stylegeom', undefined);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try and accept your answer if it helps! I'm updating the geometry once per second, so I added a test in the if statement to check if the feature geometry length is different of the style's one (see my edit).

Comment: I updated my answer to show you a better way to clear the style geometry when the feature changes. Your current way of checking then length will be very slow, because `geom.getCoordinates()` builds a coordinates array from the internal flat coordinate structure with every call.